# Convert Terraform map keys into a list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform map of accounts like below.

```html
 account_map  = {
      111111111111 = "DEV"
      222222222222 = "DEV"
      333333333333 = "STG"
      333333333333 = "PROD"
 }
```

How can I create a list of `Dev` accounts IDs as below from the above map?. I tired to use `keys` function but not sure how to search the `DEV` value inside the keys function.

```html
dev_accounts = ["111111111111", "222222222222"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For situations like this without an intrinsic function, and no possibility of a custom function, then you basically must use a `for` expression:

```
local {
  dev_accounts = [ for number, account in var.account_map : number if account == "DEV" ] # ["111111111111", "222222222222"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, Matt. It would be a great relief for me if you could help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72703713/terraform-create-a-nested-map-from-two-lists-values as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in Terraform `keys` function.

```
> keys({a=1, c=2, d=3})
[
  "a",
  "c",
  "d",
]
```

So, in your case:

```
locals {
  account_map = {
    111111111111 = "DEV"
    222222222222 = "DEV"
    333333333333 = "STG"
    333333333333 = "PROD"
  }
  dev_accounts = keys(local.account_map)
}

output "dev_accounts" {
  value = local.dev_accounts
}
```

Results to:

```
% terraform plan

Changes to Outputs:
  + dev_accounts = [
    + "111111111111",
    + "222222222222",
    + "333333333333",
  ]
...
```

Terraform docs: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/keys