# Terraform create a nested map from two lists values

Tags: terraform

I have following variable maps which I can take from terraform state outputs.

```html
account_id   = [
      "111111111111",
      "222222222222",
      "333333333333",
      "444444444444"
]

account_type   = [
      "DEV",
      "DEV",
      "STG",
      "PROD"
]
```

Now I want to create a list(map) like below. Where I only need `DEV` accounts in the map with given keys/values.

```html
      dev_accounts = [
        {
          id          = "111111111111"
          accounttype = "DEV"
        },
        {
          id          = "222222222222"
          accounttype = "DEV"
        }
      ]

Or 

  dev_accounts = [
    {
      id          = "111111111111"
    },
    {
      id          = "222222222222"
    }
  ]
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Does it really need to be `list(object)`? Could you use `map(string)` instead? It would be easier for you.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. The thing is my child module require the `dev_accounts` as a list(object). It is very difficult to change the module, as other resources already depending on the same module. But it is even fine if we exclude `accounttype = "DEV"` too as long as it returns only DEV account IDs in the same variable type. I updated the question to give more clarity.

Comment: So the other obstacle here is that there is no association between the `account_id` and `account_type` other than presumably they are in the same order, which can be dangerous to assume for all situations. You would really want to have a `map(string)` structure for your input to ensure safety.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Yes, I totally agree on what you mentioned about the obstacle. I was thinking to go with this approach because of there is no relation between `account_id` and `account_type` (Account type is a tag we put when creating the account). Therefore, we only know the account Id's after accounts are created. But I believe their Index is corresponding to each other. Could you please help me to understand what can I do with `map(string)`. Can I create `map(string)` variable from from above existing state variables?. So I can check the child module compatibility.

Comment: Instead of two lists you would have a single map of `account_id` to `account_type`.

Comment: Initially I tried the same like `dev_accounts = zipmap(local.dev_accounts, local. account_type)`. Then I realised my child module doesn't support that input. So I changed it. Let me give an another try. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: This is for your output and not your input, so the module input type would not matter.

Comment: @MattSchuchard. Thanks. I just created another thread if you can help. Thank you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72713957/terraform-dynamically-create-a-listmap

Answer (score 2):

To join your two variables into the new list you can do the following:

```
locals {
  account_id   = [
        "111111111111",
        "222222222222",
        "333333333333",
        "444444444444"
  ]

  account_type   = [
        "DEV",
        "DEV",
        "STG",
        "PROD"
  ]  
  
  joined_account = [for k,v in zipmap(local.account_id, local.account_type): {
                        id  = k
                        accounttype = v  
                   }]
  
}
```

which results in `joined_account` being:

```
[
  {
    "accounttype" = "DEV"
    "id" = "111111111111"
  },
  {
    "accounttype" = "DEV"
    "id" = "222222222222"
  },
  {
    "accounttype" = "STG"
    "id" = "333333333333"
  },
  {
    "accounttype" = "PROD"
    "id" = "444444444444"
  },
]
```

Comment: Oh!. Thanks @Marcin. I see you replied to my other question as well. But If I can fix this problem, then I'm really good with both. This seems to be solving my problem that I have been working on for few days.  Let me check and get back to you with the final outcome. Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem is, as I mentioned in the question, I have to have `joined_account` results only `DEV` accounts. Do you see any way to handle this?

Comment: Please ignore. Answer to below thread clears my problem. Thanks a lot
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72713957/terraform-dynamically-create-a-listmap/72714083#72714083