# Terraform dynamically create a list(map)

Tags: terraform

I have following `account_map`.

```html
account_map   = {
      111111111111 = "DEV"
      222222222222 = "DEV"
      333333333333 = "STG"
      444444444444 = "DEV"
      555555555555 = "PROD"
      666666666666 = "DEV"

    }
```

I'm trying something like below to get a `list(map)` output for my `instance_data` variable. (It should return only the account IDs of the `DEV`).  I know `lookup` is not going to work here. I pasted it, because this is my last try out.

```html
locals {
  instance_data = flatten([
    for account in module.organization.organization_accounts : [
      for dev_accounts in lookup(local.account_group, account.id) : {
        id = dev_accounts
      }
    ]
  ])
```

So my `local.instance_data` variable output must be something like below

```html
  + instance_data = [
      + {
          + id = "111111111111"
        },
      + {
          + id = "222222222222"
        },
      + {
          + id = "444444444444"
        },
      + {
          + id = "666666666666"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the keys and values from your map:

```
locals {

  account_map   = {
      111111111111 = "DEV"
      222222222222 = "DEV"
      333333333333 = "STG"
      444444444444 = "DEV"
      555555555555 = "PROD"
      666666666666 = "DEV"
    }

  env_map = {for k, v in local.account_map: v => k...}
}
```

then you get "DEV" accounts ids as:

```
dev_account_ids = env_map["DEV"]
```

**UPDATE**

To get exactly your desired output, you can do:

```
  env_map = [for k, v in local.account_map: {
               id = k 
            } if v == "DEV"
            ]
```

Comment: `v => k...` definitely handles the multiple keys situation, but would this not produce a `list(string)` of the `DEV` account id? That feels like a better structure, but is not the one requested in the question. Curious also why not `[ ... : k if v == "DEV" ]` instead in that case as that would be more compact and efficient.

Comment: @MattSchuchard My answer is more general. It will work for all environments, not only `DEV`.

Comment: Ok for sure; then it only matters if the alternate structure is fine, and it is definitely cleaner.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I updated the answer with code to match precisely the OP's desired output.

Comment: Already LGTM though; ergo why I upvoted.